# Client stores all images in data stream permanently

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm implementing a node server which periodically grabs images from a webcam and sends them to the client, via the node module [Delivery.js](https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js).

However, looking at the resources being used by my browser (in Chrome development tools) it seems that every image sent is being stored indefinitely by the client (or possibly by the server?).

The code I've used is similar to the "Pushing a File to a Client" example in the Delivery.js readme:

**Server code**

```
   //set the camera to take a snapshot and send it for the required framerate
        setInterval(function(){
            //take a snapshot of the current view
            cam.snapshot('./current_view.jpg' ,function( jpeg ) {
                //send this snapshot to client
                delivery.send({
                  name: 'current_view.jpg',
                  path : './current_view.jpg'
                });
            })

            delivery.on('send.success',function(file){
              //console.log('File successfully sent to client');
            });
        }, cameraUpdateDelay);
```

**Client code**

```
    var delivery = new Delivery(socket);

    delivery.on('receive.start',function(fileUID){
      //console.log('receiving a file!');
    });

    delivery.on('receive.success',function(file){
      if (file.isImage()) {
        //change the src of the img tag to the new file
        $('img').attr('src', file.dataURL());
        console.log(file);
      };
    });
```

Is it impossible to delete each file once the next is received?

Comment: You need first to track who exactly is leaking, as answer will depend on it purely.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a quick look at the client side source and every received image is added to an object, with the image's uuid being the key. If you want to cap the memory leak it likely makes sense to remove the image from the object after it's been received. On line 140 of https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js/blob/master/lib/client/delivery.js it's being added to the object:

```
_this.receiving[file.uid] = filePackage;
```

Above it, if you modify 'receive.success', to look like:

```
pubSub.subscribe('receive.success',function(filePackage){
  _this.socket.emit('send.success',filePackage.uid);
  delete _this.receiving[filePackage.uid];
});
```

That should fix the memory leak. However, you may have to do some testing to confirm that it doesn't break anything else...